# read multiple values from qtextedit and take them as distinct numbers

Tags: c++, qt

I want to read 4 values from my `QTextEdit`, and take them as 4 different values. For example, i insert `-0.69995284 0.69995284 0.14188747  0.56378639` and i want them as

`float Value1 = -0.69995284 
 float Value2 = 0.69995284 
 float Value3 = 0.14188747
 float Value4 = 0.56378639`

I begin with this:

`QString textEditValue = ui->myTextEdit->toPlainText()
QStringList lines = textEditValue .split(" ");`

but i don't know what i must do to obtain different values.

Comment: Iterate over the list and use `QString::toFloat()` for each list member. Have a look at the [foreach keyword](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your split has worked as you expect (i.e. one string for each number)

```
QVector<float> values;
int size = lines.size(); 
for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
{
  bool ok=false;
  float value = lines.at(i).toFloat(&ok);
  if(ok)
   values.push_back(value);
}
```

Values now contains your floats.

Answer (score 0):

[`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) is a container for `QString`s. Presuming that your `split` correctly filled each element in `lines` with a value you should use the iterator syntax you should use [`copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to move these values into a `vector`:

```
vector<float> Values(lines.size());

copy(lines.cbegin(), lines.cend(), Values.begin(), [](const auto& i){ return i.toFloat(); });
```